# Making flexible slider with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I wrote  a slider but It is static. When I add new image, I have to manipulate the code manually.

> How can I write this script more flexible?

*Here is my full project -> [codepen.io/FreeMaNn/pen/ZagweX](http://codepen.io/FreeMaNn/pen/ZagweX)*

**My script like this:**

```js
$("#slider-s-pic .slider-button-1").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 0) + "px" });
        });

        $("#slider-s-pic .slider-button-2").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 1) + "px" });
        });

        $("#slider-s-pic .slider-button-3").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 2) + "px" }); 
        });

        $("#slider-s-pic .slider-button-4").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 3) + "px" });
        });

        $("#slider-s-pic .slider-button-5").mouseenter(function () {
            $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 4) + "px" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mohamed-Yousef for this solution

```
$("#slider-s-pic a[class^='slider-button-']").mouseenter(function () {
    var GetIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ 
       marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * GetIndex) + "px" 
     }); });
```

`a[class^='slider-button-']` - select all classes which starts with `slider button-`

`^` - starts with `*` - contains `$` - ends with

`var GetIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();` - get the `li` index .. Don't use `$(this).index()` it'll return 0 each time .. so you need to use `.closest('li')`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are performing the same actions for each of those individual elements, to consolidate this you can simply use this instead.

Instead of targeting the button specifically, target the parent, then use jQuerys .find() method to target the slider-inner element, relative to the actual element. This means that you don't have to write a function for each individual button

```
$("#slider-s-pic).mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 1) + "px" });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your solution didn't work for me.
I guess I have not provided any information about html. My "#slider-s-pic id" and ".slider-inner ul"  class are in different list.                                         
 Here is my full project -> https://codepen.io/FreeMaNn/pen/ZagweX